# Loop through ArrayList, check condition, remove one or more items

Tags: java, arraylist

this is part of a homework assignment that isn't working properly. I was given this class of object to use:

```
private static class Segment {
    int start, end;

    Segment(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, a segment has a start and an end. Think of it as a segment of time. I want to loop through an ArrayList of Segments and if an integer falls within that segment, inclusive, the segment will be removed from the list. This is my loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < segmentList.size(); ++i) {
    if (segmentList.get(i).start <= minEnd && minEnd <= segmentList.get(i).end) {
        segmentList.remove(segmentList.get(i));
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that it doesn't remove all the segments. Take these segments:

```
4,7
1,3
2,5
5,6
```

Another method looks at ends of segments and chooses the smallest. It correctly figures minEnd is 3, it removes the 1,3 segment, **but leaves 2,5**. The correct output should be that 1,3 and 2,5 are removed in first pass. Then next pass minEnd will be 6. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: When you remove an element, the list length shrinks by one. You don't account for this; because you increase the index when you remove an element.

Comment: Elliott probably has the answer your instructor wants.  In a slightly more real example, you'd use the `listIterator()` method to get an iterator, and then use the `remove()` method on the iterator to safely (and correctly) remove elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as already given in comments, while iterating with index, removing elements will shrink the list so you wont get the desired result.

You could use an iterator to remove elements from list

```
    Iterator<Segment> it = segmentList.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Segment seg = it.next();
        if (seg.start <= minEnd && minEnd <= seg.end) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
```

Output

```
[Segment:: start 4 end 7, Segment:: start 5 end 6]
```

Java-8 streams

```
    List<Segment> segments = segmentList.stream().filter(seg -> seg.start <= minEnd && minEnd <= seg.end).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output

```
[Segment:: start 4 end 7, Segment:: start 5 end 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not going to work since you are changing the size of the collection while modifying it, this is not good since expose the code at runtime to exceptions related with trying to go beyond the range in the list.

the way to go can be:

use a temporal list, add to it the eleemnts you want to remove and then when the search is over remove the refeferences from the orginal list..

**List#removeAll(...)** willl do the trick.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-